# List of games complied or ported to Raspberry PI

Tags: arm, games

Is there a list, of games which runs natively on RPI? I mean without any emulator or Wine.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=51794

Comment: You may `sudo apt search game`, if you find one you want to install, `sudo apt-get install <gameName>`. Alternatively, use the RPi Graphical package manager: `pi-packages` and navigate to the "Games" menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some answers given in the comments. I will make them available here as a real answer.

*@CoderMike* suggested to look at the [STICKY: GAMES LIST: Games That Work On The Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=51794#p399106). There you will find a collection of games running on Raspberry Pi.

*@user96931* suggested to search the official Raspbian repository for games. You may `apt search game | less`. If you find one you want to install then do `sudo apt install <gameName>`. Alternatively, use the RPi Graphical package manager: pi-packages and navigate to the "Games" menu.